# Unity On Click() Button interface doesn't show function <SOLVED>

Tags: unity-game-engine, inheritance, button, onclick

I'm fairly new to Unity, but I've run into an issue with Button function inheritance. I have a UI object with my *game_controller* script and three buttons as child objects. When I attempt to add a function from my script to the button the *game_controller* functions won't appear.

[image: ParentObject]

I'd expected the script to be inherited from the parent, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Instead, the option simply doesn't appear. I assume the answer is something fairly simple, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Post the snippet that defined the buttons' functions. Are you sure they are public methods?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin even if the methods are public or not the `game_controller` script should have come up in the listener options

Comment: @TickMagnet have you attached the script `game_controller` to the GameObject `hold_b..` , that you have given to the OnClick Listener shown in the image ?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin - Yes they are public methods.

Comment: @sujoybyte - I did not want to attach the *game_controller* script to *hold_button* as I plan to add multiple buttons using this script, but I'm going to take that route.

Comment: @TickMagnet can you tell me why the `game_manager` script and a `Button` component are attached to the same **GameObject** ? I think it would have been better if `game_manager` is attached to a different **GameObject**

Answer (score 0):

When you try to put a **GameObject** in the **OnClick** Listener area it gets all the classes attached to that **GameObject** only (not parent) for you to able to connect your specific method from that class (for you that is `game_controller`)

As you don't want that, what you can do is,

- make variables of type `Button` inside your `game_manager` script
- attach all the GameObjects with the `Button` component
- add your methods to their respective `Button`'s `OnClick Listener`

Example code with widely and officially used naming conventions

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button HoldButton;
    public Button AnotherButton;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        // add methods to be called when the buttons are clicked
        HoldButton.onClick.AddListener(OnHoldButtonClicked);
        AnotherButton.onClick.AddListener(DoSomething);
    }
    
    private void OnHoldButtonClicked()
    {
        // what will happen when hold button is clicked
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // what will happen when another button is clicked
    }
}
```

In the inspector of `game_manager` add your Buttons to the correct `Button` fields

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the lack of inheritance.

Comment: No problem ! Have you tried the way I mentioned above, does it solves your problem ?